Weights of the posterior distribution of binomial likelihood and prior as a beta mixture
Let $(X|\theta)\sim Bin(n,\theta)$ and $f(\theta) = wf_1(\theta) + (1-w)f_2(\theta)$ where $f_1(\theta)\sim Beta(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ and $f_2(\theta) \sim Beta(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$. Find the posterior $f(\theta|x)$ after observing $X = x$
I have already found the posterior distribution as:
$\propto w \frac{\theta^{\alpha_1-1+x}(1-\theta)^{\beta_1+n-x-1}}{B(\alpha_1, \beta_1)} + (1-w) \frac{\theta^{\alpha_2-1+x}(1-\theta)^{\beta_2+n-x-1}}{B(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}$
Here I end with a posterior that is a mixture of Beta, the first one is $Beta(\alpha_1+x, \beta_1+n-x)$ and the second one is $Beta(\alpha_2+x, \beta_2+n-x)$ but the weights are the same of the prior so I am guessing that I need to find also an expression for the updated weight, but I am not really sure how to use the posterior distribution to do that.
Here is how I found the posterior distribution:
$f(\theta|x) \propto f(\theta)f(X|\theta)$
$f(\theta|x) \propto \binom{n}{x} \theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}\left(w \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\beta_1)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\beta_1)}\theta^{\alpha_1-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta_1-1} + (1-w)\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_2+\beta_2)}{\Gamma(\alpha_2)\Gamma(\beta_2)}\theta^{\alpha_2-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta_2-1}\right)$
$f(\theta|x) \propto  w\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}\frac{\theta^{\alpha_1-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta_1-1}}{B(\alpha_1, \beta_1)} + (1-w)\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}\frac{\theta^{\alpha_2-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta_2-1}}{B(\alpha_2, \beta_2)}$
